Redirect URLs containing a specific Query String to 410 using htaccess
I want to redirect any URL that contains these parameters/string option=com_content&view=article&id= to 410 page gone using htaccess
I have tried this but it doesn't work;It still loads the page instead of returning 410 gone
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_content&view=article&id= [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=410,L]
ErrorDocument 410 default

What am I getting wrong?

According to https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=f117f883-1272-47d1-996c-46fde14a598d, this should work. Can you add some details, please - where is this .htaccess located, what is an actual example URL you tested this with?

FYI: The G for "gone" flag is a bit more "explicit" way to force a 410 response. (Although the "redirect" with R=410 should also work.)

The .htaccess is located in the public_html directory.
This is a sample of the URL I want to redirect to 401:
https://farmbizafrica.com/farmbiz-tv-amaranth-mchicha-farmers-raise-earnings-by-picking-weed-for-cash-and-producing-seeds/?option=com_content&view=article&id=1157;indigenous-veges-promise-farmers-nutrients-and-profits-in-cash&catid=13

"It still loads the page instead of returning 410 gone" - I think this only sets the status code to 410 (use your browser dev tools to check the response), but if the request still matches an available resource, the content of that still will be delivered. Not sure if an internal rewrite to a different document would work, you'd have to test that. (You don't appear to have a custom error document for this, but you could create one.)

Am using the server default 410 error document (ErrorDocument 410 default) and it works for other redirects. Am just stumped why this particular one doesn't work.

Do you have an example RewriteCond and URL, for one of the cases that do work?
